# Getting error InvalidBson in pymongo code. How to solve this?

Tags: python, pymongo

```
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient

test  = MongoClient("mongodb://harikrishna:ch9u2encn4e9hc3n0284hci-032n8c4@35.200.240.21:27017/tb_dev")

testdb = test.tb_dev

import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime

import datetime as dt

import pandas as pd

from bson.objectid import ObjectId

submission = testdb.test_submission.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"createdOn":{"$gte":datetime.strptime("2020-11-30T00:00:00UTC","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"),
                            "$lt":datetime.strptime("2021-01-01T00:00:00UTC","%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")},"isQuiz":False}},
        {"$project":{"sid":1,"tid":1,"marks":1,"timeTaken":{"$divide":["$timeTaken",60]},"totalAnswered":1}}],allowDiskUse = True)

submission = pd.DataFrame(list(submission))

submission.head()
```

Trying to execute this code. But getting InvalidBSON error in *submission = pd.DataFrame(list(submission))* line. Help me in decoding this error

Comment: Could you please add what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to get Details of student ID, marks, timeTaken, test ID for some tests from MongoDB collection.